# I would like to duplicate the default product layout grid in a Commerce Kickstart2 site

Tags: commerce, theming

thanks for looking at my post!

I have a Drupal7 Commerce Kickstart2 site.  I recently cloned the default products page so I can create a new page with the same layout.  It worked great except that the product grid that displays on the original default products page doesn't show up on my new page. Instead I have a page where the products just list vertically.  How do I fix that?

Here are the links to the two pages:

https://www.subcitizen.com/products

https://www.subcitizen.com/ames-bros-m-12.html

Thanks so much for any and all info!  I really appreciate it!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

It's because the CSS for the list elements is not being applied

```
display: inline;
float: left;
min-height: 380px;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
width: 230px;
```

So you need to change the CSS selector so that it does apply.

I think that isn't the right answer though, instead of duplicating the template I think you should edit the view so that it shows your brand pages with the brand info at the top rather than put it in the template (if that is what you're doing).  It'll take a while to work out but the site will be much easier to maintain over time.